# Node js API REST service auth translate text mail node mailer

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I have developed a REST API using node js and express. 
I use node mailer to send mail when user do a registration.
I have auth services (POST method) that read the language code passing by app and send an email with translated text and token to validate the registration. The link with token is a GET request that send other mail.
How i can say to GET method which language code is used so can send a mail with translation?

Hi have implement this code to verification token:

```
// Verification token
router.get('/verification/:language/:token/', function(req, res, next) {
const language = req.params.language;

console.log(language); 


// Check for validation errors
var errors = req.validationErrors();
if (errors) return res.status(400).send(errors);

// Find a matching token
Token.findOne({ token: req.params.token }, function (err, token) {
//if (!token) return res.status(400).send({status: 'ko',error: {type: 'not-verified', msg: 'We were unable to find a valid token. Your token my have expired.'}} );
if (!token) return res.redirect('https://localhost/expiredtoken');



// If we found a token, find a matching user
User.findOne({ _id: token._userId }, function (err, user) {
  if (!user) return res.status(400).send({ msg: 'We were unable to find a user for this token.' });

  //if (user.isVerified) return res.status(400).send({status: 'ko',error:{type: 'already-verified', msg: 'This user has already been verified.'}});
  if (user.isVerified) return res.redirect('https://localhost/userverified');

  // Verify and save the user
  user.isVerified = true;
  user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }
    //res.status(200).send({status: 'ok', data: { msg: 'The account has been verified. Please log in.'}});
    res.redirect('https://localhost/login');


    //
    var text_email;
    if (language == 'en') {
      text_email = 'Hi'
    }
    if (language == 'it') {
      text_email = 'Ciao'
    }


    var client = nodemailer.createTransport(sgTransport(options));

    var email = {
        from: 'noreply@test.com',
        to: user.email,
        subject: 'Registration successfully confirmed',

        text: text_email
      };

    client.sendMail(email, function(err, json){
        if (err){
            return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message });
        }
        else {
            res.status(200).send({status: 'ok', data: { msg: 'A verification email has been sent to ' + user.email + '.'}} )
        }
    });



    //

        });
    });
});

});
```

The verification works and also the send mail but app crash with this error:
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Any help please??

Comment: If you have the language code avaialbe when validating the token, you can send language code in query parameters of GET method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GET `http://localhost/route?language=en`.

If you are using `express` you can access value of language by using `req.query.language` from your route handler.

Comment: I such cases you should accept the answer and open a new question for the new error you get

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GET method, with params in route.

Eg.:

Route: `http://your-app-domain/route?language=en`

Getting language:

```
...
app.get('/route', (req, res) => {
  const language = req.query.language;
  console.log(language); // en
});
```

http://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#express.urlencoded

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excuse me! I ended up fooling myself about the name of the route. I've corrected the answer.